# How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal

Tags: c#, hex, type-conversion, decimal

How do you convert between hexadecimal numbers and decimal numbers in C#?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

To convert from decimal to hex do...

```
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");
```

To convert from hex to decimal do either...

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

or

```
int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);
```

Comment: I would like to understand how this line decValue.ToString("X") converts it to Hex.

Comment: The variable decValue is of type Int32. Int32 has a ToString() overload that can accept one of a number of Format Strings that dictate how the value will be represented as a string. The "X" format string means Hexidecimal so 255.ToString("X") will return the hexadecimal string "FF". For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: Good answer. I am actually using int.TryParse instead of int.Parse for this to avoid having to use the annoying try catch block.

Comment: @ColeJohnson `int.Parse` doesn't have an option for you to specify the base as an `int`, just as one of a few valid `NumberStyles`. For base 16, either is just fine, but as a general solution, it's good to know how both work.

Comment: this works for anything that can be represented as an integer (including Int64) but NOT for a larger decimal or float such as 20 digit number etc.  When dealing specifically with larger numbers some of the other answers are far more correct.  Using int and decimal interchangeably is dangerous and misleading.

Answer (score 69):

Hex -> decimal:

```
Convert.ToInt64(hexString, 16);
```

Decimal -> Hex

```
string.Format("{0:x}", intValue);
```

Comment: +1 the nice thing about `Convert.ToInt64(hexValue, 16);` is that it will do the conversion if the `0x` prefix is there or not, whereas, some of the other solutions will not.

Comment: @Craig hi, so I need to do the conversion based on hex value size or I can apply ToInt64 for all hex value, will there any impact ?

Comment: Pleeeeeease, when providing a solution with something that comes from a specific namespace, indicate which namespace it is !

Comment: this works only for integer conversion folks!!Decimal throws an error.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like you can say

```
Convert.ToInt64(value, 16)
```

to get the decimal from hexdecimal.

The other way around is:

```
otherVar.ToString("X");
```

Comment: I get System.FormatException: The specified format 'x' is invalid

Comment: This works only for integer. If you want to convert a decimal hex to decimal or the other way arround it throws an error.

Answer (score 14):

If you want maximum performance when doing conversion from hex to decimal number, you can use the approach with pre-populated table of hex-to-decimal values.

Here is the code that illustrates that idea. My [performance tests](http://vadmyst.blogspot.com/2012/02/fast-convertion-of-hex-string-into.html) showed that it can be 20%-40% faster than Convert.ToInt32(...):

```
class TableConvert
  {
      static sbyte[] unhex_table =
      { -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       , 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,10,11,12,13,14,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,10,11,12,13,14,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
       ,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
      };

      public static int Convert(string hexNumber)
      {
          int decValue = unhex_table[(byte)hexNumber[0]];
          for (int i = 1; i < hexNumber.Length; i++)
          {
              decValue *= 16;
              decValue += unhex_table[(byte)hexNumber[i]];
          }
          return decValue;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Genius!  Wonder if it is possible to make the byte compiler automatically use this approach inside the Convert.ToInt32 ?

Comment: I do not see any reasons why it cannot be done. However, maintaining array will consume additional memory.

Answer (score 12):

[From Geekpedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20081231062758/http://www.geekpedia.com/KB8_How-do-I-convert-from-decimal-to-hex-and-hex-to-decimal.html):

```
// Store integer 182
int decValue = 182;

// Convert integer 182 as a hex in a string variable
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

// Convert the hex string back to the number
int decAgain = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: I used this method to make small dotnet 4.0 app in a few minutes, works great with just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

```
String stringrep = myintvar.ToString("X");

int num = int.Parse("FF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: This doesnt work on decimal hex values.
System.ArgumentException: 'The number style AllowHexSpecifier is not supported on floating point data types.'

Answer (score 2):

If it's a really big hex string beyond the capacity of the normal integer:

For .NET 3.5, we can use BouncyCastle's BigInteger class:

```
String hex = "68c7b05d0000000002f8";
// results in "494809724602834812404472"
String decimal = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(hex, 16).ToString();
```

.NET 4.0 has the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

Hex to Decimal Conversion

```
Convert.ToInt32(number, 16);
```

Decimal to Hex Conversion

```
int.Parse(number, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

[For more details Check this article](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=f3ed25f1-2563-4323-9f43-c4fbbc9c372f)

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223).

Answer (score 2):

Try using BigNumber in C# - Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

#### Program

```
using System.Numerics;
...
var bigNumber = BigInteger.Parse("837593454735734579347547357233757342857087879423437472347757234945743");
Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToString("X"));
```

#### Output

```
4F30DC39A5B10A824134D5B18EEA3707AC854EE565414ED2E498DCFDE1A15DA5FEB6074AE248458435BD417F06F674EB29A2CFECF
```

#### Possible Exceptions,

ArgumentNullException - value is null.

FormatException - value is not in the correct format.

#### Conclusion

You can convert string and store a value in BigNumber without constraints about the size of the number unless the string is empty and non-analphabets

Answer (score 1):

```
    static string chex(byte e)                  // Convert a byte to a string representing that byte in hexadecimal
    {
        string r = "";
        string chars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        r += chars[e >> 4];
        return r += chars[e &= 0x0F];
    }           // Easy enough...

    static byte CRAZY_BYTE(string t, int i)     // Take a byte, if zero return zero, else throw exception (i=0 means false, i>0 means true)
    {
        if (i == 0) return 0;
        throw new Exception(t);
    }

    static byte hbyte(string e)                 // Take 2 characters: these are hex chars, convert it to a byte
    {                                           // WARNING: This code will make small children cry. Rated R.
        e = e.ToUpper(); // 
        string msg = "INVALID CHARS";           // The message that will be thrown if the hex str is invalid

        byte[] t = new byte[]                   // Gets the 2 characters and puts them in seperate entries in a byte array.
        {                                       // This will throw an exception if (e.Length != 2).
            (byte)e[CRAZY_BYTE("INVALID LENGTH", e.Length ^ 0x02)], 
            (byte)e[0x01] 
        };

        for (byte i = 0x00; i < 0x02; i++)      // Convert those [ascii] characters to [hexadecimal] characters. Error out if either character is invalid.
        {
            t[i] -= (byte)((t[i] >= 0x30) ? 0x30 : CRAZY_BYTE(msg, 0x01));                                  // Check for 0-9
            t[i] -= (byte)((!(t[i] < 0x0A)) ? (t[i] >= 0x11 ? 0x07 : CRAZY_BYTE(msg, 0x01)) : 0x00);        // Check for A-F
        }           

        return t[0x01] |= t[0x00] <<= 0x04;     // The moment of truth.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really easiest way but this source code enable you to right any types of octal number i.e 23.214, 23 and 0.512 and so on. Hope this will help you..

```
    public string octal_to_decimal(string m_value)
    {
        double i, j, x = 0;
        Int64 main_value;
        int k = 0;
        bool pw = true, ch;
        int position_pt = m_value.IndexOf(".");
        if (position_pt == -1)
        {
            main_value = Convert.ToInt64(m_value);
            ch = false;
        }
        else
        {
            main_value = Convert.ToInt64(m_value.Remove(position_pt, m_value.Length - position_pt));
            ch = true;
        }

        while (k <= 1)
        {
            do
            {
                i = main_value % 10;                                        // Return Remainder
                i = i * Convert.ToDouble(Math.Pow(8, x));                   // calculate power
                if (pw)
                    x++;
                else
                    x--;
                o_to_d = o_to_d + i;                                        // Saving Required calculated value in main variable
                main_value = main_value / 10;                               // Dividing the main value 
            }
            while (main_value >= 1);
            if (ch)
            {
                k++;
                main_value = Convert.ToInt64(Reversestring(m_value.Remove(0, position_pt + 1)));
            }
            else
                k = 2;
            pw = false;
            x = -1;
        }
        return (Convert.ToString(o_to_d));
    }
```

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow. could you please explain a bit your code (mybe just a short sentence).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
public static decimal HexToDec(string hex)
{
  if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
    hex = "0" + hex;
  byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
  decimal d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
      raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
      d += Math.Pow(256, (raw.Length - 1 - i)) * raw[i];
    }
    return d.ToString();
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal - Hexa

```
        var decValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string hex = string.Format("{0:x}", decValue);
        Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

Hexa - Decimal (use namespace: using System.Globalization;)

```
        var hexval = Console.ReadLine();
        int decValue = int.Parse(hexval, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(decValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

**FOUR C# native ways to convert Hex to Dec and back:**

```
using System;

namespace Hexadecimal_and_Decimal
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string hex = "4DEAD";
      int dec;

      // hex to dec:
      dec = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
      // or:
      dec = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);

      // dec to hex:
      hex = dec.ToString("X"); // lowcase: x, uppercase: X
      // or:
      hex = string.Format("{0:X}", dec); // lowcase: x, uppercase: X

      Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal number: " + hex);
      Console.WriteLine("Decimal number: " + dec);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version is I think a little more understandable because my C# knowledge is not so high.
I'm using this algorithm: http://easyguyevo.hubpages.com/hub/Convert-Hex-to-Decimal (The Example 2)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Tool
{
    public static string DecToHex(int x)
    {
        string result = "";

        while (x != 0)
        {
            if ((x % 16) < 10)
                result = x % 16 + result;
            else
            {
                string temp = "";

                switch (x % 16)
                {
                    case 10: temp = "A"; break;
                    case 11: temp = "B"; break;
                    case 12: temp = "C"; break;
                    case 13: temp = "D"; break;
                    case 14: temp = "E"; break;
                    case 15: temp = "F"; break;
                }

                result = temp + result;
            }

            x /= 16;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static int HexToDec(string x)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int count = x.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            switch (x[i])
            {
                case 'A': temp = 10; break;
                case 'B': temp = 11; break;
                case 'C': temp = 12; break;
                case 'D': temp = 13; break;
                case 'E': temp = 14; break;
                case 'F': temp = 15; break;
                default: temp = -48 + (int)x[i]; break; // -48 because of ASCII
            }

            result += temp * (int)(Math.Pow(16, count));
            count--;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Decimal value: ");
        int decNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Dec {0} is hex {1}", decNum, Tool.DecToHex(decNum));

        Console.Write("\nEnter Hexadecimal value: ");
        string hexNum = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        Console.WriteLine("Hex {0} is dec {1}", hexNum, Tool.HexToDec(hexNum));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert binary to Hex

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(binary1, 2), 16).ToUpper()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and possible set Hex length and part's:

```
const int decimal_places = 4;
const int int_places = 4;
static readonly string decimal_places_format = $"X{decimal_places}";
static readonly string int_places_format = $"X{int_places}";

public static string DecimaltoHex(decimal number)
{
    var n = (int)Math.Truncate(number);
    var f = (int)Math.Truncate((number - n) * ((decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimal_places)));
    return $"{string.Format($"{{0:{int_places_format}}}", n)}{string.Format($"{{0:{decimal_places_format}}}", f)}";
}

public static decimal HextoDecimal(string number)
{
    var n = number.Substring(0, number.Length - decimal_places);
    var f = number.Substring(number.Length - decimal_places);
    return decimal.Parse($"{int.Parse(n, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}.{int.Parse(f, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An extension method for converting a byte array into a hex representation. This pads each byte with leading zeros.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Turns the byte array into its Hex representation.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToHex(this byte[] y)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in y)
        {
            sb.Append(b.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, "0"[0]));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class HexadecimalToDecimal
{
    static Dictionary<char, int> hexdecval = new Dictionary<char, int>{
        {'0', 0},
        {'1', 1},
        {'2', 2},
        {'3', 3},
        {'4', 4},
        {'5', 5},
        {'6', 6},
        {'7', 7},
        {'8', 8},
        {'9', 9},
        {'a', 10},
        {'b', 11},
        {'c', 12},
        {'d', 13},
        {'e', 14},
        {'f', 15},
    };

    static decimal HexToDec(string hex)
    {
        decimal result = 0;
        hex = hex.ToLower();

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
        {
            char valAt = hex[hex.Length - 1 - i];
            result += hexdecval[valAt] * (int)Math.Pow(16, i);
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Hexadecimal value");
        string hex = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        //string hex = "29A";
        Console.WriteLine("Hex {0} is dec {1}", hex, HexToDec(hex));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a good candidate for a **`Convert`** extension method so that one could write: `int hexa = Convert.ToHexadecimal(11);` =)

Answer (score -1):

My solution is a bit like back to basics, but it works without using any built-in functions to convert between number systems.

```
    public static string DecToHex(long a)
    {
        int n = 1;
        long b = a;
        while (b > 15)
        {
            b /= 16;
            n++;
        }
        string[] t = new string[n];
        int i = 0, j = n - 1;
        do
        {
                 if (a % 16 == 10) t[i] = "A";
            else if (a % 16 == 11) t[i] = "B";
            else if (a % 16 == 12) t[i] = "C";
            else if (a % 16 == 13) t[i] = "D";
            else if (a % 16 == 14) t[i] = "E";
            else if (a % 16 == 15) t[i] = "F";
            else t[i] = (a % 16).ToString();
            a /= 16;
            i++;
        }
        while ((a * 16) > 15);
        string[] r = new string[n];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            r[i] = t[j];
            j--;
        }
        string res = string.Concat(r);
        return res;
    }
```