# Hex operations in C#

Tags: c#, hex

Any hints on parsing / converting / operating on hex values in c# ?

In particular I want to cast a decimal int to hex and then output as a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Int32 decValue = 42;
string hexValue = decValue.ToString("X");

Int32 decValue2 = Int32.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

See this post:

[How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hex-and-decimal-in-c)