# How do I serialize a System.Windows.Media.Color object to an sRGB string?

Tags: wpf, serialization, colors

I need to serialize a color used in a WPF application to a database. I'd like to use the sRGB values, because they're more familiar to those of us that have spent the last few years doing web development.

How can a get an ARGB string (like #FFFFFFFF) from a System.Windows.Media.Color object?

**UPDATE**: I was misled by the documentation on MSDN. As @Kris noted below, the documentation for the `ToString()` method is incorrect. Although it says that ToString() "creates a string representation of the color using the ScRGB channels", it will actually return a string in ARGB hex format if the color was created using the `FromARGB()` method. It's an undocumented feature, I suppose.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606572.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you create your colors using either Color.FromRgb or Color.FromArgb instead of FromScRgb you should get a hex string result from ToString.

If you want to do it manually

```
string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);
```

You can use int.Parse(,NumberStyles.HexNumber) to go the other way.

Note sRGB and scRGB refer to different color spaces, make sure your using the one you want.

Comment: You mean that if I created the Color object using FromArgb, ToString will return the ARGB hex string instead of the ScRgb value? That contradicts what it says in the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606572.aspx.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that in the documentation but it does generate a hex format when using those methods. Looking in reflector a flag is set which is used in the ToString implementation.

Comment: Yup. ToString() gives me the format I want. Looks like the MSDN documentation is incomplete.

Comment: ToString works if created as mentioned. 
 https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,7df649cf464cd38e,references

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it this way:

```
string myHex = new ColorConverter().ConvertToString(myColor);
```

Comment: There is no such method in `ColorConverter`

Comment: @EmpereurAiman it's inherited https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92ybstc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can't you just use .ToString()

Comment: This calls Color.ToString() internally.

Answer (score 5):

I created a struct to handle conversion and serialisation. It solves two problems for me: it is serialisable and it corrects the spelling ;)

```
[Serializable]
public struct Colour
    {
    public byte A;
    public byte R;
    public byte G;
    public byte B;

    public Colour(byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b)
        {
        A = a;
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
        }

    public Colour(Color color)
        : this(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B)
        {
        }

    public static implicit operator Colour(Color color)
        {
        return new Colour(color);
        }

    public static implicit operator Color(Colour colour)
        {
        return Color.FromArgb(colour.A, colour.R, colour.G, colour.B);
        }
    }
```

Just use `Colour` where you would otherwise use `System.Windows.Media.Color`

Comment: Dude, `Color` is american spelling. `Colour` is British.

Comment: It's called sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to serialize to a file and deserialize back to the color object, I think you are better of to convert color to an Int32 and vice versa. It is no brainier to serialize/deserialize Int32. If this is your purpose, here is the code:
Color To Int32:

```
        byte[] color = new byte[4];
        color[0] = Color.B;
        color[1] = Color.G;
        color[2] = Color.R;
        color[3] = Color.A;
        Int32 intColor = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(color, 0);
```

Int32 To Color:

```
byte[] bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(intColor);
Color =new System.Windows.Media.Color(){B= bytes[0], G=bytes[1], R=bytes[2], A=bytes[3]};
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for GDI colors, and not WPF, so might not be much help.

You can get the HTML color string (and back) like this

```
System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F5F7F8");
String strHtmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
```

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.aspx) is the MSDN documentation.

Comment: That is for System.Drawing.Color (GDI+), not System.Windows.Media.Color (WPF).

Answer (score 1):

There is inbuild implementation for System.Windows.Media.Color toString() method which gives hexcode of the color.

Snippet from the class interface it self

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a string representation of the color using the sRGB channels.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The string representation of the color. The default implementation represents
        //     the System.Byte values in hex form, prefixes with the # character, and starts
        //     with the alpha channel. For example, the System.Windows.Media.Color.ToString()
        //     value for System.Windows.Media.Colors.AliceBlue is #FFF0F8FF.
        public override string ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the A, R, G and B values from a Color instance as bytes, so you just need to convert the bytes to hex and concatenate the hex values as strings.

[byte[] to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-byte-to-hex-string)