# How to sort the predefined colors by color value or by brightness like on the color palette in google drive?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, colors

I bind the `ItemsSource` of my `ListBox` as:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <sys:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
                Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</sys:String>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"
    MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

**My Xaml for ListBoX :**

```
<ListBox x:Name="coloListBox" Style="{x:Null}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}, 
         Converter={StaticResource ColSortConverter}}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource ColorToStringConverter}}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="15" Height="15" Stroke="#FF211E1E" OpacityMask="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel Width="250" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

**Converter**

```
public class ColorSortConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] colorsProperties = null;
        var result = value as PropertyInfo[] ;

        if (result != null)
        {
            colorsProperties = result;
            colorsProperties.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToArray();
            return colorsProperties;
        }
        return colorsProperties;
    }
}
```

How to sort the array in the converter in order to get the colors sorted by their HEX value or according to the brightness?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply bind to a sorted collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hex-Values**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301653/2249175) you can use `System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter` to get the hex values of colors

```
var colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
string hexColorValue = colorConverter.ConvertToString(myColor);
```

When you have a list of colors, you could simply do

```
List<Color> SortByHex(List<Color> colors)
{
    var colorConverter = new ColorConverter();
    return color.OrderBy(c => colorConverter.ConvertToString(c)).ToList();
}
```

**Brightness**

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036477/2249175) on how to convert a `System.Windows.Media.Color` to a brightness.

```
public static float GetBrightness(System.Windows.Media.Color c)
{
    return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B).GetBrightness();
}
```

cf.

```
List<Color> SortByBrightness(List<Color> colors)
{
    return color.OrderBy(GetBrightness).ToList();
}
```

**Please note:** The proposed options won't work in your code *out-of-the-box*, but you'll have to figure out how to use them in your code. Anyway, they should suffice as a starting point.

Comment: and you can get the Color from the PropertyInfo by just calling `(Color)info.GetValue(null)`, so you could basically just call `result.OrderBy(x => ((Color)x.GetValue(null)).GetBrightness()).ToList()` assuming you created the extension Method GetBrightness for Color, according to Paul's post.