# Convert byte array to int

Tags: c#

I am trying to do some conversion in C#, and I am not sure how to do this:

```
private int byteArray2Int(byte[] bytes)
{
    // bytes = new byte[] {0x01, 0x03, 0x04};

    // how to convert this byte array to an int?

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); // is this correct? 
    // because if I have a bytes = new byte [] {0x32} => I got an exception
}

private string byteArray2String(byte[] bytes)
{
   return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

   // but then I got a problem that if a byte is 0x00, it show 0x20
}
```

Could anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: You could just use a cast if you like living life on the edge.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`BitConverter` is the correct approach.

Your problem is because you only provided 8 bits when you promised 32.  Try instead a valid 32-bit number in the array, such as `new byte[] { 0x32, 0, 0, 0 }`.

If you want an arbitrary length array converted, you can implement this yourself:

```
ulong ConvertLittleEndian(byte[] array)
{
    int pos = 0;
    ulong result = 0;
    foreach (byte by in array) {
        result |= ((ulong)by) << pos;
        pos += 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

It's not clear what the second part of your question (involving strings) is supposed to produce, but I guess you want hex digits?  `BitConverter` can help with that too, as described in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-byte-to-hex-string).

Comment: a list of bytes is fine as I declared as above I think

Comment: `foreach` in byte conversion look really insane(

Comment: @Mikant: Can you explain what you think the problem is?  It works for me: http://ideone.com/ML8Nb

Comment: usually we use such a type of conversion to gain speed... not to worry about the environment we work in. `foreach` sugar may slow the `work` up to hundreds of times... i just want to say that usage of the `foreach` keyword 'must' be consciously recognized

Comment: @Mikant: I think you're confusing this with some other case.  `foreach` on arrays is very fast.  If there were a generic interface here, such as `IEnumerable<byte>`, there could be performance problems.  But the code I show has no "hundreds of times" overhead.  You could probably squeeze out a few more percent by unrolling, but that's all.

Comment: How can I go back from ulong to my own bytes array?

Comment: This function you suggested gives warning: warning CS0675: Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first. Why?

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first), 
// reverse the byte array. 
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. this is correct, but you're
   missing, that `Convert.ToInt32`
   'wants' 32 bits (32/8 = **4** bytes)
   of information to make a conversion,
   so you cannot convert just One byte:
   `new byte [] {0x32}
2. absolutely the the same trouble
   you have. and do not forget about
   the encoding you use: from encoding to encoding you have 'different byte count per symbol'

Comment: 1 is OK. question 2 is not clear for me, so which encoding format should I use? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A fast and simple way of doing this is just to copy the bytes to an integer using Buffer.BlockCopy:

```
UInt32[] pos = new UInt32[1];
byte[] stack = ...
Buffer.BlockCopy(stack, 0, pos, 0, 4);
```

This has the added benefit of being able to parse numerous integers into an array just by manipulating offsets..