# c# convert byte array of ascii values to integer array

Tags: c#

I have a *byte array* of `50` bytes representing `5` integers as ascii characters values. Every integer value is represented as `10` bytes:

```
byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[] {
  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 49,  // 9 spaces then '1'
  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 50,  // 9 spaces then '2'
  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 49, 50, 51, 52,  // 6 spaces then '1' '2' '3' '4'
  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 53, 56, 48, 49,  // 6 spaces then '5' '8' '0' '1'
  20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 57, 57, 57}; // 7 spaces then '9' '9' '9'
```

Please, notice that `20` is an ascii code of `space` and `[48..57]` are ascii codes of `0..9` digits.

How can I convert the byte array to an *integer array* (`int[] intvalues == [1, 2, 1234, 5801, 999]`)?

I have tried first to convert byte array to string and then string to integer like this:

```
string[] asciival = new string[10];
int[] intvalues = new int[5];

Byte[] receiveBytes = '20202020202020202049  //int value = 1
                       20202020202020202050  //int value = 2
                       20202020202049505152  //int value = 1234
                       20202020202053564849  //int value =5801
                       20202020202020575757';//int value = 999

asciival[0] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes, 0, 10);
asciival[1] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes, 10, 10);

intvalues[0] = int.Parse(asciival[0]);
intvalues[1] = int.Parse(asciival[1]);
```

But isn't there a simpler way to copy the byte array into the string array?

Comment: Maybe duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165171/convert-byte-array-to-int

Comment: How do you make `int` that is 10 bytes wide ? `sizeof(int) == 4`

Answer (score 1):

A for loop can simplify the writing:

```
byte[] recv = new byte[]{ /* ... */ }

int[] intvalues = new int[recv.Length / 10];

for(int pos = 0; pos < recv.Length; pos += 10)
    intvalues[pos / 10] = int.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv, pos, pos + 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using *Linq*:

- Split initial array on 10-items (i.e. 10-`byte`) chunks
- Filter digits (`'0'`..`'9'` )  in each chunk
- `Aggergate` digits into a single integer

Implementation:

```
  using System.Linq;
  ...

  Byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[] {
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 49,  // 9 spaces then '1'
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 50,  // 9 spaces then '2'
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 49, 50, 51, 52,  // 6 spaces then '1' '2' '3' '4'
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 53, 56, 48, 49,  // 6 spaces then '5' '8' '0' '1'
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 57, 57, 57}; // 7 spaces then '9' '9' '9'

  int[] intvalues = Enumerable.Range(0, receiveBytes.Length / 10)
    .Select(index => receiveBytes
       .Skip(index * 10) // Skip + Take: splitting on 10-items chunks
       .Take(10)                  
       .Where(b => b >= '0' && b <= '9') // just digits 
       .Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 10 + a - '0')) 
    .ToArray();
```

Test

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", intvalues));
```

Outcome:

```
  1, 2, 1234, 5801, 999
```

Please, notice, that `10` digits number can well *overflow* `int` since maximum `int` value (`int.MaxValue`) is `2147483647` only. To represent the initial `byte[]` as a `string` you can use *Linq* once again:

```
  var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, receiveBytes.Length / 10)
    .Select(index => receiveBytes
       .Skip(index * 10) // Skip + Take: splitting on 10-items chunks
       .Take(10)
       .Select(b => b.ToString("00"))) // enforce leading "0" if necessary
    .Select(items => string.Concat(items));

  string text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);

  Console.Write(text);
```

Outcome

```
20202020202020202049
20202020202020202050
20202020202049505152
20202020202053564849
20202020202020575757
```

Comment: To be honest, I find the OP's initial code (`Encoding.ASCII.GetString` followed by `int.Parse`) much easier to read & understand.

Comment: @stakx: it depends on what bytes can appear in the initial `receiveBytes` array; if digits and spaces only then I agree. If, say, it can have `160` (non-breaking space), `95` (underscope), `0` (`'\0'`) etc. as placeholders then I'd rather stick to `Where` + `Aggregate`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :-

```
using System;
using System.Text; 
class Example
{ 
  public static void Main()
  { 
  // Define a string. 
  String original = "ASCII Encoding"; 
 // Instantiate an ASCII encoding object.
   ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding(); 
// Create an ASCII byte array.
  Byte[] bytes = ascii.GetBytes(original); 
// Display encoded bytes.
  Console.Write("Encoded bytes (in hex): ");
  foreach (var value in bytes)
    Console.Write("{0:X2} ", value);
    Console.WriteLine(); // Decode the bytes and display the resulting Unicode string. 
    String decoded = ascii.GetString(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Decoded string: '{0}'", decoded);
  }
}
```