# How to remove a char from a string, based on its codepage index?

Tags: c#, string, char, codepages

I am writing a .NET-software in C# that should transfer data from one database to another.
Every character with an index greater than 127 **of codepage 1252** causes trouble in the target database, so I want to remove those characters from the values (strings), before I write them into the target database.

I have been searching and trying a lot, but until now I have only found solutions for doing that for ASCII or UTF indexes. I need a solution for indexes of codepage 1252.

Edit: here is my closest approach so far:

```
protected string GetSqlValue(string input, bool isStringValue = true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return "''";
    else
    {
        //TODO: remove all characters with an index greater than 127 in codepage 1252.
        Encoding targetEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        byte[] tmp = targetEncoding.GetBytes(input);
        for (int i=0;i<tmp.Length;i++)
        {
            if (tmp[i] > 127) tmp = tmp.Where((source, index) => index != i).ToArray();
        }
        input = targetEncoding.GetString(tmp);

        if (isStringValue) return "'" + input + "'";
        else return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Most importantly, show us the code you have so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: I have no working code so far for this topic. Actually I have a methods `protected string GetSqlValue(string input)` that returns "NULL", if the parameter is null, empty or consists of whitespaces only. if that is not the case, the methods simply returns the parameter so far. My request here is something that I want to add to this methods, so far I haven't even come close to a solution.

Comment: okay, I have added what I think is my closest approach so far.

Answer (score 0):

Before I show you a solution to your question, I'd suggest, that you have a look at your encodings (in DB and Code) and solve those problems instead of removing chars.

Your solution ignores that a single char can be represented by multiple bytes. Here a unicode example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("a: " + string.Join("-", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("a").Select(s => s.ToString("X2"))));
Console.WriteLine("€: " + string.Join("-", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("€").Select(s => s.ToString("X2"))));
```

You have to check every char in your string and choose only those which match your requirement.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "abc€def!\"§$%&/()=?`";

    var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

    Console.WriteLine("All:     " + str);
    // Select all chars which have a total value below 128
    IEnumerable<char> chars = str.Where(s => ConvertLittleEndian(enc.GetBytes(s + "")) < 128);

    // reassamble string
    Console.WriteLine("Reduced: " + String.Concat(chars));
}

static ulong ConvertLittleEndian(byte[] array)
{
    int pos = 0;
    ulong result = 0;
    foreach (byte by in array)
    {
        result |= ((ulong)by) << pos;
        pos += 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The static method `ConvertLittleEndian()` is a copy of the first answer from this question:
[Convert byte array to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165171/convert-byte-array-to-int)

Comment: I think the problem of multiple bytes for single chars does not matter here, because codepage 1252 has only 256 values, so it should always be one byte per char. please correct me if I am wrong with that assumption.

Comment: Correct for Codepage 1252, but if he would only use this codepage, the DB wouldn't be a problem. I think he has a bigger problem with the encodings. Anyway the solution i provided will work for him.

Comment: Maybe I should explain the origin of the problem. The goal of my software is, like I said before, to transfer data from one database to another. that is part of an ERP exchange of the company that I work for. The problem is that the source database is setup for international usage, while the destination database is setup für German only (LanguageID 1031 with codepage 1252). As a result of that setup of the target database characters with an index greater than 127 in codepage 1252 are not supported by the target database, because they are not part of the German alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I have been mistaken about the origin of my problem.
It turned out that some data also contained several aposthophes. Those destroyed the DDL and DML statements for the target database.
I also had to prevent German umlauts from been deleted too.

so the final version of my methods now looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the SQL value as German characters of codepage 1252.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The string to convert for the target database.</param>
/// <param name="isStringValue">if set to <c>true</c> return encapsulated in single quotation marks.</param>
/// <returns>"''", or the value itself.</returns>
protected string GetSqlValue(string input, bool isStringValue = true)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return "''";
    else
    {
        Encoding targetEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

        // Remove all characters that are not part of codepage 1252.
        input = targetEncoding.GetString(targetEncoding.GetBytes(input));

        // Remove unsupported special characters.
        byte[] tmp = targetEncoding.GetBytes(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
        {
            // Don't delete German umlauts.
            if (tmp[i] == 0xc4 /* Ä */ || tmp[i] == 0xe4 /* ä */ || tmp[i] == 0xd6 /* Ö */ || tmp[i] == 0xf6 /* ö */ || tmp[i] == 0xdc /* Ü */ || tmp[i] == 0xfc /* ü */) continue;

            // Delete non German characters and all kind of apostrophes.
            if (tmp[i] >= 0x80 || tmp[i] < 0x20 || tmp[i] == 0x27 || tmp[i] == 0x60) tmp = tmp.Where((source, index) => index != i).ToArray();
        }
        input = targetEncoding.GetString(tmp);

        if (isStringValue) return "'" + input + "'";
        else return input;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

P.S.: I know this question was not as it should have been. I will do better once I get more into how things should be done here.