# How to form 32 bit integer by using four custom bytes?

Tags: c#, integer, byte, bitwise-operators

I want to create a `32` bit *integer* programmatically from four `byte`s in hex such as:

Lowest byte is `AA`

Middle byte is `BB`

Other middle byte is `CC`

Highest byte is `DD`

I want to use the variable names for that where:

```
byte myByte_1 = 0xAA
byte myByte_2 = 0xBB
byte myByte_3 = 0xCC
byte myByte_4 = 0xDD
```

So by using the above bytes and using bitwise operations how can we obtain: `0xDDAABBCC` ?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just `BitConverter.ToInt32`. Seeing if there's a good duplicate for that (in c#)

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165171/convert-byte-array-to-int

Comment: `int result = unchecked((myByte_4 << 24) | (myByte_3 << 16) | (myByte_2 << 8) | myByte_1);`

Comment: Ok I understood now it works for me. Thank you all. Should I delete the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct such `int` *explicitly* with a help of bit operations:

```
int result = myByte_4 << 24 | 
             myByte_3 << 16 | 
             myByte_2 << 8 | 
             myByte_1;
```

please, note that we have an *integer overflow* and `result` is a *negative* number:

```
Console.Write($"{result} (0x{result:X})");
```

**Outcome;**

```
-573785174 (0xDDCCBBAA)
```

`BitConverter` is an *alternative*, which is IMHO *too wordy*:

```
int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
  ? new byte[] { myByte_1, myByte_2, myByte_3, myByte_4 }
  : new byte[] { myByte_4, myByte_3, myByte_2, myByte_1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by asking C# to make us a struct that shares memory space for its members:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Bynteger{

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Lowest;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Middle;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte OtherMiddle;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Highest;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint UInt;

}
```

If you assign to those bytes then read the `int` or the `uint` you'll get the value:

```
var b = new Bynteger{
    Lowest = 0xAA,
    Middle = 0xBB,
    OtherMiddle = 0xCC,
    Highest = 0xDD
}; 

Console.WriteLine(b.Int);                //prints -573785174
Console.WriteLine(b.UInt);               //prints 3721182122
Console.WriteLine(b.UInt.ToString("X")); //prints 0xDDCCBBAA
```

> how can we obtain: 0xDDAABBCC ?

Er.. If `0xDD AA BB CC` isn't a typo (did you mean to say 0xDD **CCBBAA**`?), you can jiggle the layout around by changing the number in the FieldOffset, e.g.:

```
[FieldOffset(2)]
public byte Lowest;
[FieldOffset(1)]
public byte Middle;
[FieldOffset(0)]
public byte OtherMiddle;
[FieldOffset(3)]
public byte Highest;
```

Will give you the 0xDD**AABBCC** you requested, if you keep the assignments you said (Lowest = 0xAA etc)

You're free to name the fields however you like too.. (perhaps B1 to B4 ?)