# How to change byte[] to hex?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa, in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)
>   [C# byte[] to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-byte-to-hex-string)

I need to take this:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

And turn it into something like this:

```
0x01020304
```

What is the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-byte-to-hex-string

Comment: Forgive me for the duplicate.  I must lack the knowledge needed to understand this.  I didn't see any of the other questions show how to put it in "0x01020304" format.  Did I miss that anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

For a single value:

`String.Format("{0:X2}", value);`

Depending on what the array represents you can then do some string concatenating to put all the bits together.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
foreach (byte b in ba)
{
       sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
}
return sb.ToString();
```