# Why isn't my PHP SHA256 hash equivalent to C# SHA256Managed hash

Tags: c#, php, sha256

Why aren't these the same?

php:

```
    $hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
```

c#

```
    public static string ComputeHash(string plainText, string salt)
    {
        // Convert plain text into a byte array.
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);

        SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();

        // Compute hash value of salt.
        byte[] plainHash = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

        byte[] concat = new byte[plainHash.Length + saltBytes.Length];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(saltBytes, 0, concat, 0, saltBytes.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(plainHash, 0, concat, saltBytes.Length, plainHash.Length);

        byte[] tHashBytes = hash.ComputeHash(concat);

        // Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
        string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(tHashBytes);

        // Return the result.
        return hashValue;
    }
```

Comment: Because the question is flawed. It is _equivalent_. Only it doesn't _look_ the same

Comment: that may be so, but I added base64_encode() and they still do not produce the same output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# is outputting a base64 ecoded string, and PHP is outputting a number in hex. A better comparison might be to pass the parameter true to the end of the hash function of PHP and base64 the result:

```
 $hash = base64_encode(
           hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password), true )
         );
```

Comment: Thank you for you're quick response!

I tried this and tho they are now closer, they do not produce the same output. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Lemontongs have you made any changes to the above code...I am getting a differnt result in php and c#

Answer (score 3):

Because they're different. Your C# code encodes the computed hash in Base64 encoding at the end. PHP just returns a string of hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

First suspect:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
```

C# uses UTF-8, your PHP probably doesn't, but you could be lucky if you use strictly letters from the US-ASCII subset.

Second suspect:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(tHashBytes);
```

There's nothing about Base64 in your PHP.

Since PHP will give you a hex-encoded result, you should switch to Hex in your C#, too. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-byte-to-hex-string) for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm no C# programmer, but one thing that leaps out at me is this:

```
// Convert result into a base64-encoded string.
string hashValue = Convert.ToBase64String(tHashBytes);
```

Are you base64-encoding the final output in C#? Because you're not in PHP...

Answer (score -1):

```
C#
string toHash = "abcdefg";
SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();
byte[] signatureData = hash.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(toHash));
string hashResult = System.Convert.ToBase64String(signatureData);
PHP
print base64_encode(hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding("abcdefg","UTF-16LE"),true));
```

Write like top code,They are the same

Answer (score -1):

C#

```
string toHash = "abcdefg"; 
SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed(); 
byte[] signatureData = hash.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(toHash)); 
string hashResult = System.Convert.ToBase64String(signatureData);
```

PHP

```
print base64_encode(hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding("abcdefg","UTF-16LE"),true));
```

Works for me.