# Converting Encryption used in C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, arrays, sha256

I have been trying to convert a C# encryption technique to PHP. The C# code is as given below. I have no experience in C#. I had to take over project in C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //byte[] response = ComputeHash("pradeep14520", BitConverter.GetBytes("0x9A111B734E4F10469668"));
    //byte[] response = ComputeHash("pradeep14520", dictionary.ElementAt(0).Value.Salt);
    byte[] response =ComputeHash("pradeep14520", StringToByteArray("9A111B734E4F10469668"));
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(response).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(response); // 683CA8E00E8CE41A079B7C86CE4960AC2376CD85F2AEAB2E4DF99FFA7F7FA4F3
}

 private byte[] ComputeHash(string password, byte[] storedSalt)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        if ((int)storedSalt.Length > 0)
        {
            byte[] passwordAndSalt = new byte[(int)passwordBytes.Length + (int)storedSalt.Length];
            passwordBytes.CopyTo(passwordAndSalt, 0);
            storedSalt.CopyTo(passwordAndSalt, (int)passwordBytes.Length);
            passwordBytes = passwordAndSalt;
        }

        return new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
    }
```

I have commented the sample response in the button click function. I tried to implement the same functionality using PHP. with the below code after referring [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249998/why-isnt-my-php-sha256-hash-equivalent-to-c-sharp-sha256managed-hash)

.I have found that there is no need to produce byte arrays in PHP as strings are byte arrays in php.

```
$originalSalt = 'pradeep14520';
    $originalSalt .= '9A111B734E4F10469668';
    hash("sha256",iconv(mb_detect_encoding($originalSalt, mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8", $originalSalt),true);
```

I have passed the last argument to the hash function as false inorder to get raw output.
But i am getting different Output for PHP and C#

```
for PHP :afc80d1a6cae81e8f868b054dafbb74bdd86399d771fceef574e4b373506b704
for C#  :683CA8E00E8CE41A079B7C86CE4960AC2376CD85F2AEAB2E4DF99FFA7F7FA4F3
```

Plz help.
Thanks in advance.

Based on the suggestion provided by Daniel Hilgarth i have modified the code and made it work.

```
   $password = 'pradeep14520';
$originalSalt = hex2bin('9A111B734E4F10469668');
echo    strtoupper(hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding($password,"UTF-16LE").$originalSalt,false));
```

I hope it will help someone..

Comment: ...and your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the C# code uses [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx). This is UTF-16, i.e. it returns two bytes per character, even if the character is representable in ASCII.

You need to use an equivalent of this in PHP or change your C# code to use either [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) or [`Encoding.ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx), depending on what PHP strings really are.

Comment: In the link that i have mentioned they made it as correct answer. And there is nothing like UTF encoding and all. I have tried without encoding and still it shows the same output.

Comment: @shanavascet: No. The linked question uses `Encoding.UTF8` just as I said. You are using `Encoding.Unicode`.