# C# Sha256 hash doesn't equal PHP

Tags: c#, php, hash, sha256

I'm building a website and their current login system is in C#. I'm building the site in PHP and would like to keep the passwords the same for their customers. In order to do that, I need to make their hashing function the same as mine. I'm having a bit of trouble since I don't know much about C#.

Here are the C# functions that I've found that are useful to setting the password when I decompiled the code:

```
string salt = ui.UserGUID.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInfoProvider.UserSaltColumn))
  salt = ui.GetStringValue(UserInfoProvider.UserSaltColumn, string.Empty);
ui.SetValue("UserPassword", (object) UserInfoProvider.GetPasswordHash(userPassword, stringValue, salt));
```

The GetPasswordHash function will return this:

```
return SecurityHelper.GetSHA2Hash(password + salt + UserInfoProvider.PasswordSalt);
```

The GetSHA2Hash function is where I think my problems are. Here's the one-liner of the function:

```
return ValidationHelper.GetStringFromHash(new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputData)));
```

And finally, here's the GetStringFromHash function:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (byte hashByte in hashBytes)
    stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0:x2}", (object) hashByte));
  return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

In the first code, stringValue is sha256 which pulls the second like of code. The salt is stored in the database so I know what that value is, and I know a non-encrypted password to test. In the second piece of code, the "salt" variable is null so it's only hashing the password and the salt in the database.

I have tried several different pieces of PHP code to try to get the passwords to match, but nothing so far. Here's a few of the things I've tried:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', ord("Password" . "The Salt"));
$hash = hash('sha256', "Password" . "The Salt");
$hash = (hash('sha256', mb_convert_encoding("Password" . "The Salt","UTF-8"), true));
```

I know the last piece of code is formatting the string into hexadecimal, but I am at a loss right now. I'm hoping it's a simple fix. I spent the better part of yesterday tracking down all the functions and trying to get it to work before bringing it here.

Thanks in advance.

---

Solved. Apparently, the GUID was being lowercased in the first line:

```
string salt = ui.UserGUID.ToString();
```

and that was causing the issues to be wrong. I created an online fiddle and when I was getting the same output as PHP, I knew there was something was was being changed. Looked into it a little more and then we found the problem. Here's the final PHP in case it helps future people:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', "Password" . strtolower("The Salt"));
```

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark, but it looks like you're hashing different strings. In C#, you have `password + salt + UserInfoProvider.PasswordSalt`, whereas in PHP you just have `"Password" . "The Salt"`. Do you perhaps have two salts in the first example, a global one and also a user specific one?

Comment: `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` try to use UTF8 instead. Also, you're concatenating twice the salt: `salt + UserInfoProvider.PasswordSalt`.

Comment: The question lack [MCVE] (which should include both C# and PHP code + sample data). Also this question asked so many times already - i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249998/why-isnt-my-php-sha256-hash-equivalent-to-c-sharp-sha256managed-hash ...

Comment: iann - The "salt" value is null. I stated that after the C# code.
Gusman - I'll try UTF8. Same as above though.
Alexei - I've already seen that and tried the answers there after modifying them. I wouldn't have asked If I knew the answer. I've done my research.

Comment: You should really be using an HMAC, not just concatenation a salt the password. But you should also be using an iteration method that requires about 100 ms per password such as bcrypt, password-hash or PBKDF2 as examples–if you want security. Hashing is incredible fast these days, 1,000,000 SHA-256 hashes per seconds is easily done on a single laptop.

Comment: No this is not duplicate question. Because he get each byte hash by mask 
`{0:x2}`  this mask is x2 each byte in string. We have 3-step securite, 1.step is salt, 2.step is converting string 3. step encode. For php you need repeat this steps.

Comment: zaph - I know, I know. I need to verify they are logging in with the right password before I can update it.
Naumov - What is the hexadecimal string being encoded to?

Comment: You can show hash, password and salt, for repiat.