# hex representation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, hash, ripemd

If I want the following result :

```
RIPEMD-160("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") =
 37f332f68db77bd9d7edd4969571ad671cf9dd3b
```

I tried this :

```
string hash11 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RIPEMD.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")));
```

but it doesn't give me the previous result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ComputeHash function gives you a byte array with the values in it (0x37, 0xF3, ...). If you use GetString it will take every value in the byte and use the character with that value, it will not convert the value into a string.

You could convert it like that:

```
var bytes = RIPEMD.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
string hash11 = "";
foreach(var curByte in bytes)
    hash11 = curByte.ToString("X2") + hash11; // or curByte.ToString("X") if for example 9 should not get 09
```

Like that you have the highest byte at the beginning. With

```
hash11 += curByte.ToString("X2")
```

you have the lowest byte at the beginning.

Comment: `3BDDF91C67AD719596D4EDD7D97BB78DF632F337`
!!

Comment: Ye, thats the right string, just read it from behind:
37F332F68DB77BD9D7EDD4969571AD671CF9DD3B

As i stated in my answer you need to append the bytes either at the start of the end of the string, depending if you want the highest byte first or last.

Comment: I want the following :

`37f332f68db77bd9d7edd4969571ad671cf9dd3b`

Comment: Well, and whats now the problem? Is it because the letters are uppercase? If so you can steer that with the `X` in `ToString`. Using `X` gives uppercase, `x` lowercase.


/Edit: Just read your other comment:
Just use the other way then. If you now use `hash11 = curByte.ToString("X2") + hash11;` use `hash11 += curByte.ToString("X2");` instead and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to get is the **hex representation** of the byte array: each byte should be represented by its two-character hex value.

You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/c-sharp-byte-to-hex-string) for several different examples on how to do that.