# How to convert a byte[] to a string with {#, #, #} format?

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have a helper function that will create a key or vector byte array for use in encryption methods. However I need a method that will take the `byte[]` and output the following representation of the values as a `string` from the byte array:

```
//I need the output to look like this:
    "{241, 253, 159, 1, 153, 77, 115, 174, 234, 157, 77, 23, 34, 14, 19, 182, 65, 94, 71, 166, 86, 84, 50, 15, 133, 175, 8, 162, 248, 251, 38, 161}"
```

I found this long hand method to use which *technically* works but it's a mess, especially with having to remove the last comma:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    var hex = new StringBuilder(byteArray.Length * 2);
    foreach (var b in byteArray)
        hex.AppendFormat("{0}, ", b);

    var output =  "{"+ hex.ToString() + "}";
    return output.Remove(output.Length - 3, 2); //yuck
}
```

This seems to be a highly asked question and I found several posts with solutions, but none of the suggestions output the string from the `byte[]` as I need above. I checked the following:

[byte[] to hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string)
[How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

I used several of the parsing and LINQ examples but none of them output the byte array elements in the string as I needed above.

Is there a way to convert the actual values of the byte array returned from my helpwer method to the string format I need without using that hack of a method?

Comment: Looks almost like JSON. If you can change format to real JSON ("[1,3,5]") than consider using either built in JSON serializer or JSON.Net one.

Comment: Actually this represents a `key` and `iv` values used in encryption and decryption method not JSON. It's already in the form of a `byte[]` so I need a method to deal with it in this form.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx

Comment: @TimothyShields - I already tried `var output = BitConverter.ToString(key);` and that did not produce the output I required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very handy [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join.aspx) is the key to what you want.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return "{" + string.Join(", ", byteArray) + "}";
}
```

If you're encoding for the computer, and not to pretty print to a human, [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) may be a better way to encode these bytes. It allows for much more compact encoding. E.g. this code:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
}
```

Produces the 44-character `8f2fAZlNc67qnU0XIg4TtkFeR6ZWVDIPha8Iovj7JqE=` instead of the 142-character string you gave to encode these 32 bytes.  And converting back to a `byte[]` is just `Convert.FromBase64String(theString)`, instead of having to split and parse the long string yourself.

**Update:** Here's an option for compact code generation:

```
public static string ByteArrayEncoded(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return "Convert.FromBase64String(\""+Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)+"\")";
}
```

Use like:

```
string generatedLine = "private static readonly byte[] defaultVector = "
                         + ByteArrayEncoded(myArray) + ";";
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for with this question. Nice job!

Comment: So I could replace the following: `private byte[] defaultVector = { 146, 64, 191, 111, 23, 3, 113, 119, 231, 121, 252, 112, 79, 32, 114, 156 };` with `private byte[] defaultVector = mJhaxtPOq+DqHvO9+QmR2oSlAKzna68L04BEeKL4u7Y=` I don't think the later would work as I've typed it though?

Comment: If the intent is to write C# code, the pretty print solution is probably the best. To use a base64-encoded string in that way, you'd do `private byte[] defaultVector = Convert.FromBase64String("mJhaxtPOq+DqHvO9+QmR2oSlAKzna68L04BEeKL4u7Y=");` But that makes it have to parse a string at runtime - not as nice as being declared for the compiler to know about.

Comment: +1. @atconway, you probably should have asked actual problem... `private byte[] defaultVector = Convert.FromBase64("mJhaxtPOq+DqHvO9+QmR2oSlAKzna68L04BEeKL4u7Y=")` would give much more compact generated code (and either version is not human readable anyway).

Comment: @TimS. - I like it explicitly declared as opposed to having to parse at runtime as well. Actually I use this in a test harness to produce these random keys for different apps. So the output is actually then copied and pasted into different apps.

Comment: If the base 64 encoding is the approach you want to take, I've added a method to my answer that'll help with that.