# How get I get the hex type data using the commands below

Tags: c#, hex, getstring

I want to get a hex type data using getstring, but I don't know C# very well. How can I modified the code to implement the function? I have a device keep sending the hex data to my PC via socket. I find the socket program below to receive the hex type data, but later the display of the receiving data are totally messy code that doesn't make any sense. I don't know if I use the wrong type of data or some problems else. Can anyone help me to solve it, thanks a lot!

I revised my program according to the suggestions, it give me some string as I desired, but later a serial of 000000 was printed out, and it never stop. Why it happened like this?

```
 public void ReceiveMsg()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int recv = newclient.Receive(data);
            Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            //string stringdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            showMsg(hexString + "\r\n");

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting.?and you want to convert string data to Hex or  Hex data string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement will covert your Byte Array to string.

```
string stringdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);
```

The following code converts Byte Array to Hex string

```
StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 2);
foreach (byte b in data)
   hexString.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
```

or you can use

```
string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```

Comment: I revised it according to your suggestion, anyway it works partially. I got the first few word as I desired, but later on uncountable "00000" was printed out, and it never stop. Anyone knows why it goes like this way?

Comment: @user2863859 what is the input you are giving?

Comment: @user2863859 check for inputs here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string>

Comment: @user2863859 for ex:byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x33, 0x43, 0xFE } ; string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(data);Output : "33-43-FE"

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is still there. I print out the outgoing messages on my computer to check if I can send the right messages. The printout looks exactly right. But on the receiving terminal I can only receive the beginning of the messages, the following messages are all changed to a nonstop serial of "0". The printout never stop on Receiving side even after the sending program stopped.

Comment: Please don't put the code in while() loop,because this will be infinite loop or there is no exit of the while() loop,it is always true.