# SHA256 giving 44 length output instead 64 length

Tags: c#, sha256

I am using the following code to perform SHA256.

```
public static string GenerateSaltedHash(string plainTextString, string saltString)        
        {            
            byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltString);
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextString);
            HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

            byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
              new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
            {
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainText[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
            {
                plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];
            }
            byte[] bytes = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes));                              
        }
```

As I am using SHA256, I expect the length of the result to be 64. But I am getting 44.

What is the issue? Will the shorter length output impact security?

Comment: As a guess - it looks like you're converting it into a Base64 string instead of the standard Hex string - which would give a different length.

Comment: SHA256 will give you 32 bytes as a hash. using Base64 encoding of this gives you approx 44 chars. as @origin said, if instead you represent each byte as its hex value (2 chars) then you'll get 64 chars.

Comment: Ya  I think its right. I have converted each byte to string with X2 format & I am getting length of 64.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Base-64 is 6 bits per character (2^6 = 64).

```
256 bits / 6 bits per char = 42.6666 char
```

And that has obviously ended up as 44 due to padding (you will see one or 2 `=` on the end of the output).

You must be expecting base-16 (AKA hexadecimal) which is 4 bits per character (2^4 = 16).

```
256 bits / 4 bits per char = 64 char
```

For hex use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623184/360211):

```
return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Are there any differences in security by using this method or the Base64 method?

Comment: No, they are both just encodings. Anyone with the base 64 or base 16 information can get back to the original binary representation easily.