# How to generate HMAC SHA 256 using hmacutils in java

Tags: java, hmac, sha

I've been trying to generate an HMAC for an API using code like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] hmacSha256 = HmacUtils.hmacSha256(API_SECRET, "totalParams");

    System.out.println((Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSha256)));
}
```

But when I use the string I get in my API call I receive the error:

> {"code":-1100,"msg":"Illegal characters found in parameter
>   'signature'; legal range is '^[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}$'."}

I thought that it meant I had to convert to hex, but the hex is not working either.

I don't care about the implementation, I just want a valid signature. Anyone know how to generate a valid signature in any way?

Comment: Does your API_SECRET contains chars different than 0-9 and a-f?

Comment: Yes. Should I be converting that to a hex then?

Comment: What version are you using commons-codec, 1.10 or 1.11?

Comment: Why using `HmacUtils`? You can do it all with [`javax.crypto.Mac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html).

Comment: This gives me the exact same HMAC, which is not working.

Comment: Note that Base64 encoding also uses two characters other than letters and digits. (Letters and digits alone would give only 62 possibilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817617/195833) to a similar question, and then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) to convert your `byte[]` to hex instead of using Base64.

(Short version: You've got 256 bits of hash, and the API is expecting 64 characters. Base64 gives you 44(ish), but hex should give you 64)