# How can i convert c# socket data to hex data?

Tags: c#

I write this simple code to get data from socket:

```
private void DataReceive()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];
                int byteRec;

                while (true)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        byteRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        if (byteRec > 0)
                        {
                            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRec);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    FillLstMsg(data);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

but i want to get data from HEX format,or i see data in hex format?,how can i do this?

Comment: All data transfered between computers is binary. Hex Data is human friendly representation of binary data.

Comment: @KellermanRivero i buy tk-06 gps tracker-thats send hex data to socket

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you out. These show the conversion from `Byte` to `HEX`. Even if this may not be exactly what you want, you might get the next step that you are looking for.

[Get HEX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string)

[Array conversion to HEX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Hope this helps.