# SHA1 encoding not working as expected in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following string: `TheString = 12424$456$06$4539527688361959$2017$188.98.78.191$`

I want the SHA1 Hash of that string and for that I'm using the following code:

```
string TheSHA1Hash = BitConverter.ToString(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TheString)));
```

This is the output:

```
8F-BA-36-2C-FC-DE-31-B2-AC-66-07-37-2D-80-85-63-5A-33-35-F4
```

When I go to http://www.sha1-online.com/ and hash the string, this is the output, which is what I want:

```
8fba362cfcde31b2ac6607372d8085635a3335f4
```

It looks the same but it's not the same. How can I get the output I want?

Comment: it looks like in lazy way, removing dashes and putting it in lower case will make you work done :D <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the dashes (with `Replace()`) and make lowercase (with `ToLower()`).

```
string TheSHA1Hash = BitConverter.ToString(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TheString))).Replace("-","").ToLower();
```

Here it is in a format that is a bit easier to read:

```
var hasher = new SHA1Managed();
var hash = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TheString));
var byteString = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
var theSHA1Hash = byteString.Replace("-","").ToLower();
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the output of BitConverter (which includes dashes), you can roll your own array-to-hex converter.  See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) to see how.