# 1-digit hexadecimal convertion in c#?

Tags: c#, hex

I would like to convert an `Int32` in the range `0-15` into a the corresponding `char` in hexadecimal. One really dummy solution consists in writing

```
var hex = new[] {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
                 '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
var myCharInHex = hex[myValue];
```

Yet, this solution looks plain wrong, any better suggestion?

Comment: if you are completely sure that your int is always in that range and you want a mapping of int->char I find your solution plain excellent :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hex-and-decimal-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works for your exact specification, but I'd personally do it as:

```
private static readonly char[] HexDigits = "0123456789abcdef".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple code must work:

```
string hexValue = myValue.ToString("X");
```

Comment: but it returns a string, not a char