# Numeric Converter (big integers in string format)

Tags: c#, algorithm, valueconverter

I'm trying to write a class in C# that converts a big number (string format) to any number system, I found this code at [How to convert a gi-normous integer (in string format) to hex format? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652760/how-to-convert-a-gi-normous-integer-in-string-format-to-hex-format-c)

```
    var s = "843370923007003347112437570992242323";
    var result = new List<byte>();
    result.Add( 0 );
    foreach ( char c in s )
    {
        int val = (int)( c - '0' );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < result.Count ; i++ )
        {
            int digit = result[i] * 10 + val;
            result[i] = (byte)( digit & 0x0F );
            val = digit >> 4;
        }
        if ( val != 0 )
            result.Add( (byte)val );
    }

    var hex = "";
    foreach ( byte b in result )
        hex = "0123456789ABCDEF"[ b ] + hex;
```

This code also works for any numeric system (2^n base) with a few modifications to the code.

The problem is that I do not understand the logic of the algorithm (the for statement).
Can someone please explain this part of the code:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < result.Count ; i++ )
{
    int digit = result[i] * 10 + val;
    result[i] = (byte)( digit & 0x0F );
    val = digit >> 4;
}
if ( val != 0 )
    result.Add( (byte)val );
```

In order to make this code to convert, for example, a string decimal to a string base64, I need to change the mask so it can calculate six bits, instead of just four for the hex system, and then right-shift digit by 6 to add the remaining to the next byte.

```
 result[i] = (byte)( digit & 0x03F );
 val = digit >> 6;  // 2^6 = 64
```

and finally just change the look-up table to print the result

```
hex =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/" [ b ] + hex;
```

It is this line in the for-loop the one I don't totally understand

```
int digit = result[i] * 10 + val;
```

What is this line, along with the loop, doing on each iteration to every byte of result? and most importantly, why?

Comment: Sort of figuring it out.  Let's say string was just '8'. Then digit = 8, result[i] = 8, val = 0, no added byte => 8 (1 byte).  Next char is 4; digit is 84, result[0] is 5, val is 4 => 54 (2 bytes).

Comment: 54 hex is 84 decimal.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I upvoted, why downvotes people? and why the close as off-topic, its a question about `a software algorithm`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson it is a copy/paste from the other question and does not show minimal understanding about the problem.

Comment: Algorithm was not explained in original post. And he cited it.

Comment: fair enough, OP could step through code to understand the bit-wise and bit-shift operations.

Comment: I do understand the code, the bit-wise and bit-shift operators, in fact I modified the code so it can convert any integer (string decimal format) to any numeric system with base 2 to the n. Maybe i was not cleared with my question, but what I would like to know is the logic of the algorithm. So, yes @JeremyThompson, this is a software algorithm question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the code is easier to understand if you compare the algorithm to the simpler version where the integer can be represented in an `int`. Then `result` would be a 32 bit integer which you would initialize to 0 and for each digit you would multiply the existing value of `result` with 10 and add the next digit:

```
int result = 0;
foreach ( char c in s ) {
  int val = (int)( c - '0' );
  result = 10*result + val;
}
```

For big integers you need a byte array to represent the integer and the loop that you want to understand is a way to multiply the value in the byte array of unknown length with 10 while also adding the digit value. Because multiplying by 10 is not a simple bit shift you need that extra code.