# Displaying IEEE-754 quadruple-precision (binary128) floating point values in scientific notation in C#

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to translate the raw binary data from a thread context into a human-readable format, and have come up empty when trying to translate [quadruple-precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_quadruple-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary128) values into a readable format in C#.

Ultimately, I'd like to display it in standard scientific notation, e.g. 1.234567×10<sup>89</sup>. I'm not worried about loss of precision in the process - I just want a reasonable idea of what the value is.

My first thought was to manually compute the value as a double by raising the exponent, but of course I'm going to exceed the maximum value in many cases. I don't mind losing precision, but not being able to display it at all isn't acceptable.

Is there some kind of simple mathematical hack I can use for this?

Comment: Are you allowed quad-precision computations for the purpose of converting to decimal, or do you have to do everything with integers and doubles? Is a quad-precision function `pow` available?

Comment: How much loss of precision is acceptable?  If you're willing to accept relative errors of around 10**-12, then you could compute the log (in base 10, say) of the value using its exponent and the first 53 bits of its mantissa, and then retrieve the decimal exponent and significand from the integral and fractional parts of that log, respectively.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I understood the individual words, but the overall meaning was lost on me. Care to post an answer that's a bit more "ELI5"?

Comment: @MarkDickinson On the precision aspect, I don't mind too much. I'm just displaying it for purposes of making a reasonable guess when debugging something. The raw hex will be displayed too - I just want a "human readable" form to make things clearer.

Comment: @Polynomial: I've attempted an answer; I hope you don't mind Python - I know a little bit of C#, but it would take me much longer to come with an answer in C#, and I'm supposed to be catching a flight shortly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install a third-party library that handles that. For example it looks like [QPFloat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpfloat/) gives you a new `struct` called `System.Quadruple` which overrides `ToString`, so you could try that.

(I wonder when .NET will support something like `System.Quadruple`.)

Comment: While I would've preferred to handle it myself, QPFloat did the job. I still had to manually hack the code together to get the raw data into the type, but at least I have a single type that can hold that level of precision safely.

Answer (score 3):

So here's an answer to expand on the comment I made earlier.  I hope you don't mind that I'm using Python, since I know where to find everything I need in that language; maybe someone else can translate this into a suitable answer in C#.

Suppose that you've got a sequence of 128 bits representing a number in IEEE 754 binary128 format, and that we've currently read those 128 bits in in the form of an unsigned integer `x`.  For example:

```
>>> x = 0x4126f07c18386f74e697bd57a865a9d0
```

(I guess this would be a bit messier in C#, since as far as I can tell it doesn't have a 128-bit integer type; you'd need to either use two 64-bit integers for the high and low words, or use the `BigInteger` type.)

We can extract the exponent and significand via bit operations as usual (I'm assuming that you already got this far, but I wanted to include the computation for completeness):

```
>>> significand_mask = (1 << 112) - 1
>>> exponent_mask = (1 << 127) - (1 << 112)
>>> trailing_significand = x & significand_mask
>>> significand = 1.0 + float(trailing_significand) / (2.0**112) 
>>> biased_exponent = (x & exponent_mask) >> 112
>>> exponent = biased_exponent - 16383
```

Note that while the exponent is exact, we've lost most of the precision of `significand` at this point, keeping only 52-53 bits of precision.

```
>>> significand
1.9393935334951098
>>> exponent
295
```

So the value represented is around `1.9393935334951098 * 2**295`, or around `1.234567e+89`.  But you can't do the computation directly at this stage because it might overflow a `Double` (in this case it doesn't, but if the exponent were bigger you'd have a problem).  So here's where the logs come in: let's compute the natural log of the value represented by `x`:

```
>>> from math import log, exp
>>> log_of_value = log(significand) + exponent*log(2)
>>> log_of_value
205.14079357778544
```

Then we can divide by `log(10)` to get the exponent and mantissa for the decimal part: the quotient of the division gives the decimal exponent, while the remainder gives the *log* of the significand, so we have to apply `exp` to it to retrieve the actual significand:

```
>>> exp10, mantissa10 = divmod(log_of_value, log(10))
>>> exp10
89.0
>>> significand10 = exp(mantissa10)
>>> significand10
1.234566999999967
```

And formatting the answer nicely:

```
>>> print("{:.10f}e{:+d}".format(significand10, int(exp10)))
1.2345670000e+89
```

That's the basic idea:  to do this generally you'd also need to handle the sign bit and the special bit patterns for zeros, subnormal numbers, infinities and NaNs.  Depending on the application, you may not need all of those.

There's some precision loss involved firstly in the conversion of the integer significand to a double precision float, but also in taking logs and exponents.  The worst case for precision loss occurs when the exponent is large, since a large exponent magnifies the absolute error involved in the `log(2)` computation, which in turn contributes a larger relative error when taking `exp` to get the final significand.  But since the (unbiased) exponent doesn't exceed 16384, it's not hard to bound the error.  I haven't done the formal computations, but this should be good for around 12 digits of precision across the range of the `binary128` format, and precision should be a bit better for numbers with small exponent.

Answer (score 1):

there are few hacks for that...

1. **compute hex string for number**

   mantissa and exponent are in binary so there should be no problem just do not forget to add zero for each `2^4` exponent part and shift the mantissa by `exponent&3` bits. Negative exponents need few tweaks but are very similar.

   All of this can be done by bit and shift operations so no precision loss if coded right ...
2. **convert hex string to dec string**

   there are quite a few examples also here on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214) is mine. You can also tweak it a little to skip zero processing for more speed...
3. **now scan the dec string**

   if you look at mine `dec2hex` and `hex2dec` conversions in link above then the scan is already there you need to find:

   - the position of first nonzero decimal from left and right
   - position of decimal point

   from these you easily compute exponent
4. **convert dec string to mantissa * 10^exponet form**

   it is quite straight forward just remove zeros ... and translate decimal point to its new position then add exponent part ...
5. **add sign for mantissa**

   you can add it directly in bullets **#1,#2** but if you do it in the end then it will spare you a few `if`s ...

Hope this helps ...