# Trying to understand simple big number calculations

Tags: c++, math, computation-theory, bignum

I am trying to better understand how 'big numbers' libraries work, (like **GMP** for example).

I want to write my own function to `Add()` / `Subtract()` / `Multiply()` / `Divide()`

The class is traditionally defined ...

```
std::vector<unsigned char> _numbers; // all the numbers
bool _neg; // positive or negative number
long _decimalPos; // where the decimal point is located
                  // so 10.5 would be 1
                  //    10.25 would be 2
                  //    10 would be 0 for example
```

First I need to normalise the numbers so I can do

Using 2 numbers
    10(x) + 10.25(y) = 20.25

For simplicity, I would make them the same length,

For x:
    _numbers = (1,0,0,0) decimal = 2

For y:
    _numbers = (1,0,2,5) decimal = 2

And I can then reverse add x to y in a loop

```
...
// where x is 10.00 and y is 10.25
...
unsigned char carryOver = 0;
int totalLen = x._numbers.size();
for (size_t i = totalLen; i > 1 ; --i )
{
    unsigned char sum = x._numbers[i-1] + y._numbers[i-1] + carryOver;
    carryOver = 0;
    if (sum > _base)
    {
     sum -= _base;
     carryOver = 1;
    }
    numbers.insert( number.begin(), sum);
}

// any left over?
if (carryOver > 0)
{
  numbers.insert( number.begin(), 1 );
}

// decimal pos is the same for this number as x and y

...
```

The example above will work for adding two positive numbers, but will soon fall over once I need to add a negative number to a positive number.

And this gets more complicated when it comes to subtracting numbers, then even worse for multiplications and divisions.

Can someone suggest some simple functions to Add() / Subtract() / Multiply() / Divide()

I am not trying to re-write / improve libraries, I just want to understand how they work with numbers.

Comment: If you know how to do long arithmetic with pencil and paper, you don't need a library. If you don't, a library won't help you.

Comment: At least you're dealing with simple not complex numbers.. :P

Comment: Did you try to have a look to the implementation this kind of feature? (on https://gmplib.org/devel/repo-usage.html), you will probably have better details about implementation than the one we can give here in 2 or 3 lines.
Nevertheless, I would say that people write lib exactly because they don't want to bother with the complexity of implementation when they use the lib. If things were trivial and really simple, probably you wouldn't even think to making them a lib.

Comment: Yes, I did have a look at it, but for obvious reasons they optimise a lot of their code, and how simple calculations are done is lost in some of those optimisations. I just wanted to try understand the logic of some of those libraries.

Comment: @FFMG finished edditing

Comment: [This question in Java.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5318068/2336725)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**addition and substractions are pretty straightforward**

You need to inspect signs and magnitudes of operands and if needed convert the operation to/from `+/-`. Typical C++ implementation of mine for this is like this:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
arbnum arbnum::operator + (const arbnum &x)
    {
    arbnum c;
    // you can skip this if you do not have NaN or Inf support
    // this just handles cases like adding inf or NaN or zero
    if (  isnan() ) return *this;
    if (x.isnan() ) { c.nan(); return c; }
    if (  iszero()) { c=x; return c; }
    if (x.iszero()) return *this;
    if (  isinf() ) { if (x.isinf()) { if (sig==x.sig) return *this;
                    c.nan(); return c; } return *this; }
    if (x.isinf()) { c.inf(); return c; }
    // this compares the sign bits if both signs are the same it is addition
    if (sig*x.sig>0) { c.add(x,this[0]); c.sig=sig; }
    // if not
    else{
        // compare absolute values (magnitudes)
        if (c.geq(this[0],x)) // |this| >= |x| ... return (this-x)
                {
                c.sub(this[0],x); 
                c.sig=sig;    // use sign of the abs greater operand
                }
        else    {             // else return (x-this)
                c.sub(x,this[0]);
                c.sig=x.sig;
                } 
        }
    return c;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
arbnum arbnum::operator - (const arbnum &x)
    {
    arbnum c;
    if (  isnan() ) return *this;
    if (x.isnan() ) { c.nan(); return c; }
    if (  iszero()) { c=x; c.sig=-x.sig; return c; }
    if (x.iszero()) return *this;
    if (  isinf() ) { if (x.isinf()) { if (sig!=x.sig) return *this;
                    c.nan(); return c; } return *this; }
    if (x.isinf()) { c.inf(); c.sig=-x.sig;  return c; }
    if (x.sig*sig<0) { c.add(x,this[0]); c.sig=sig; }
    else{
        if (c.geq(this[0],x))
                {
                c.sub(this[0],x);
                c.sig=sig;
                }
        else    {
                c.sub(x,this[0]);
                c.sig=-x.sig;
                }
        }
    return c;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where:

- `geq` is unsigned comparison greater or equal
- `add` is unsigned `+`
- `sub` is unsigned `-`

**division is a bit more complicated**

see:

- [bignum divisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32945407/2521214)
- [approximational bignum divider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398246/2521214)

  For divisions you need to have already implemented things like `+,-,*,<<,>>` and for some more advanced approaches you need even things like: **absolute comparison** (you need them for `+/-` anyway) , **sqr**, number of used **bits** usually separate for fractional and integer part.

  The most important is the **multiplication** see [Fast bignum square computation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18465326/2521214) because it is core for most division algorithms.

**performance**

for some hints see [BigInteger numbers implementation and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23967901/2521214)

**text conversion**

If your number is in ASCII or in `BASE=10^n` digits then this is easy but If you use `BASE=2^n` instead for performance reasons then you need to have fast functions capable of converting between `dec` and `hex` strings so you can actually load and print some numbers to/from your class. see:

- [How do I convert a very long binary number to decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33799814/2521214)
- [How to convert a gi-normous integer (in string format) to hex format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps!