# Why do BigInteger implementations use sign-magnitude instead of two's complement?

Tags: math, data-structures, binary, biginteger, arbitrary-precision

Arbitary-precision signed integers are almost always implemented using a sign-magnitude representation:

- (Java) [BigInteger](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/3d3e8a33701e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l131) in OpenJDK
- (Python) [Bigint](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c) implementation of the Python built-in int type in CPython
- (C) [mpz_t](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html#Integer-Internals) in GMP, the GNU multiple precision arithmetic library
- (C++) [BigInteger](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/bigint.git/blob/HEAD:/BigInteger.hh#l26) in a bigint library by Matt McCutchen
- (Rust) [BigInt](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/blob/master/src/bigint.rs#L112-L115) in the num-bigint library

The clear preference for sign-magnitude stands in contrast to the near-universal preference for two's complement in fixed-width signed integer types. The question is, **why is sign-magnitude so clearly preferred for BigIntegers?** (I welcome counterexamples if you disagree with the premise.)

Note that BigInteger APIs typically specify "as-if two's complement" semantics (e.g. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=integer#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)), for bitwise operations where it matters. This provides consistency with the usual meaning of those operations. This does not dictate the actual internal representation (merely an implementation detail), but it should be a point in favor of using two's complement internally, if all else were equal.

Floating-point numbers use sign-magnitude, unlike ints which use two's complement. Floating point is not really a guiding precedent here, though, since the behavior and algorithms for floating-point arithmetic are significantly different from integer arithmetic. Bignums are much more like ints than floats.

We know the "textbook" reasons for why two's complement works mathematically and why it has advantages. It seems to me that those reasons apply equally validly to both ints and BigIntegers. To what extent is that really true?

There is, of course, a vast difference between the design constraints of hardware fixed-precision integers and software arbitrary-precision integers. In this sense, it is not at all surprising to see that designers made different tradeoffs in these different domains. What, then, are the tradeoffs between sign-magnitude and two's complement, as applied to arbitrary-precision integers? For example, this could be in terms of the performance or simplicity of certain important algorithms.

I hope your answer will illuminate the design considerations that go into BigInteger arithmetic, as well as help me re-examine what I know about two's complement from a new perspective.

*(To be clear: When I say two's complement for arbitrary-precision integers, I mean a representation using an array of words whose bit pattern, when put together, is the two's complement representation of the desired number - perhaps with the additional requirement that there be no "unnecessary leading 0's" (for nonnegative numbers) or "unnecessary leading 1's" (for negative numbers).)*

Comment: I fixed the link for Python; the link you had pointed to the specialist and somewhat restricted bigint implementation used by float-to-string and string-to-float conversion, and has nothing to do with Python's `int` type.

Answer (score 6):

Two's complement makes add and subtract a bit simpler for equal length numbers, but makes multiply and divide more complicated. For hardware implementation, there may be a time penalty, but not always. Looking at X86 "Ivy Bridge" instruction table, the only case where two's complement shows up in taking more time is for a 128 bit signed dividend divided by a 64 bit signed divisor. So this is mostly an issue for software based math.

Big integer libraries may use more complex but faster representations for large numbers. Here are some links to example articles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/big-integer.html

http://www.apfloat.org/ntt.html

The more complex methods are mostly faster for fairly large numbers, for medium size numbers, simpler implementations will be faster.

Comment: The advantages of two's complement are probably also less applicable due to having values represented by different length bit-strings (I don't think adding would be so simple for numbers of different lengths).

Comment: @Dukeling - I updated my answer to note the simpler case was for equal length numbers.

Comment: Also, one doesn't have to sign extend numbers in sign-magnitude.

Comment: FWIW, the more complex representations mentioned in the link are usually only used for special purposes. E.g. one doesn't do division, the other has big problems doing addition or subtraction. Most use either binary bases (2^32 or 2^64) or decimal bases (e.g. 10^9 or 10^19).

Comment: " since the behavior and algorithms for floating-point arithmetic are significantly different from integer arithmetic". Actually, in the end, they are not. FP is (more or less) shifted until the exponents match, and then the arithmetic is the same. There is just an additonal rounding and shifting step.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - Regarding complexity, I was thinking methods used for say 50 digits versus 100,000 digits. For FP based implementations, my impression is the element range is restricted to integer values so that the intermediate calculations are exact. [Division algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large-integer_methods) are normally used to avoid using actual divide instructions.

Comment: @rcgldr: I didn't mean FP-based algortihms, I meant algorithms that actually perform FP arithmetic. They are not as different as many may think (after all, they operate on the shifted significand, which is just a big integer). And for BigIntegers, you can use similar algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

As I build few of my own `bignum` libs I agree with **rcgldr**'s answer (+1) two's complement brings up problems in higher operations not just `*,/`.

On top of all of this some `bignum` libraries do not use power of `2` as base and using two's complement for such is also trickery. The reason for not using power of `2` is that we are computing in base `10` so we expect input and result in such. The [conversion between base 2 (or power of 2) and base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231860/2521214) is IIRC `~O(n^2)` task and for really big numbers it usually costs more than the operation performed on them. So the libs use the biggest power of `10` that fits into [ALU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214) word used ... for example in 32 bit it is `1 000 000 000` This make slight waste of space but ease up the input and output conversions between number and string representations to `O(n)`. Where `n` is number of digits or words used ...

Also two's complement complicates modulo arithmetics needed for many underlaying operations like [multiplication by NTT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

The twos complement handling and recovery will take `O(n)` while separate sign just `O(1)` which is the main reason for this I think.

Comment: The conversion between base 10 and base 2 can be much faster than O(n^2). See e.g. [Richard P. Brent and Paul Zimmermann, "Modern Computer Arithmetic", 1.7.2 Subquadratic algorithms](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4710v1.pdf) or my BigInteger implementation (https://github.com/rvelthuis/DelphiBigNumbers/blob/master/Source/Velthuis.BigIntegers.pas).