# Simple Data Masking Algorithm

Tags: c#, data-masking

Is there a simple algorithm where by I can convert a numeric value to alphanumeric 
and reliably convert it back to the same number?

For example, `12345` converts to `00A3DF` and back to `12345`.

Comment: Better write that example in code, is 12345 a string or an int? And does it have to be hexadecimal Alhpabumeric? Why not "12345" ?

Comment: Are you talking about base conversion (i.e. decimal to base-36), or encryption?

Comment: ex:  string j= "12345"  -> string s = "00A3DF"

Comment: Except 12345 != 00A3DF in any conversion I know. It's definitely not hex, and doesn't seem like any obvious encryption like ROT13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you say alphanumeric you mean hexadecimal.  This has already been answered:

[How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hex-and-decimal-in-c)
[C# convert integer to hex and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again)