# String.Format chokes on decimal values?

Tags: decimal, hex, string.format

I expect both tests below (written for NUnit) to pass, but the Decimal version fails with, "System.FormatException:  Format specifier was invalid", as does a Double version.  I cannot figure out why.  Can someone please shed light?

Thanks;
Duncan

```
[Test]
public void Integer_Format_Hex()
{
    //Assume
    Int32 myValue = 11101110;

    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert
    Assert.That( String.Format( "0x{0:X8}" , myValue ) , Is.EqualTo( "0x00A963B6" ) );
}

[Test]
public void Decimal_Format_Hex()
{
    //Assume
    Decimal myValue = 11101110m;

    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert
    Assert.That( String.Format( "0x{0:X8}" , myValue ) , Is.EqualTo( "0x00A963B6" ) );
}

[Test]
public void Decimal_Format_Hex2()
{
    //Assume
    Decimal myValue = 11101110m;

    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert
    Assert.That( myValue.ToString( "X" ) , Is.EqualTo( "00A963B6" ) );
}
```

Comment: Dear sweet jeebus method names

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert numbers between Hex and Decimal in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hex-and-decimal-in-c)

Comment: @Woot4Moo: no argument!  
@Chris Lively:  it's certainly related, but the code samples in the link you provide appear to FAIL when used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=VS.90).aspx

"The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format specifier **except for D, R, and X**...."

Awesome.