# Converting doc to txt and also convert the entities using c#?

Tags: c#, spire.doc

How do I convert a doc file with UTF-8 entity characters and automatically convert the the entities to its proper hexadecimal NCR sequence (e.x. `&#xABCD;`)

Below is a sample text from a doc file:

```
Isto é um teste. Eu não me importo com o que você pensa.
Você acha que me conhece muito bem.
```

After converting this to txt file the output should be:

```
Isto &#x00E9; um teste. Eu n&#x00E3;o me importo com o que voc&#x00EA; pensa.
Voc&#x00EA; acha que me conhece muito bem.
```

I did.

```
Document document = new Document();

    string docPath = @"C:\Users\Tamal\Desktop";
    document.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.docx"));
    document.SaveToFile(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"), FileFormat.Txt);

    string readText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"));
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

But this outputs the text file as (exactly the way the doc file is):

```
Isto é um teste. Eu não me importo com o que você pensa.
Você acha que me conhece muito bem.
```

How and where do I add the entity hexadecimal conversion?

**NOTE:** I am using *Spire.Doc* for converting doc to txt.

Answer (score 0):

Run your string through System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: I replaced the last two lines of code by
`string readText = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"));
   System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(readText);
   File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"),readText);
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(docPath,"op.txt"));`, but it does nothing?

Comment: something like this `string encodedString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(readText);`

Comment: but the output shows `Isto &#233; um teste. Eu n&#227;o me importo com o que voc&#234; pensa.
Voc&#234; acha que me conhece muito bem.` thats a different encoding

Comment: They should be equivalent. If you need the hex encoding it is more work. Take a look here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663538/how-to-convert-unicode-character-to-its-escaped-ascii-equivalent-in-c-sharp