# How to Convert VB hex to c# hex

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I convert this from VB.Net to c#?

```
Dim dd As String = Hex(ExpiryDate.Value.Day).PadLeft(4, "0")
```

I tried a conversion tool (It uses the mono project source code they say) 
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

and it came up with this but c# does not like it. - the code that is.

```
string dd = Conversion.Hex(ExpiryDate.Value.Day).PadLeft(4, "0");
```

This is the error:-

```
The name 'Conversion' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hex-and-decimal-in-c

Comment: It's sometimes better to just ask (but search first!) for what you are looking for, than by looking for some means to turn A into B in hopes of finding it ;-)

Comment: Thanks - I am new to this so forgive me if I seem a bit confused!  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
string dd = String.Format("{0:x4}", ExpiryDate.Value.Day);
```

Comment: Dim read as String = Int("&H" & buffer.Substring(0, 4)).ToString.PadLeft(2, "0")

Comment: I worked it out!  Sorry for the trouble!
           read = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(ReadString.Substring(00, 4), 16));