# How to convert hexadecimal "string" into actual hexadecimal value in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

I need to be able to take a hexadecimal string and convert it into actual hexadecimal value in .NET.  How do I do this?

For instance, in Delphi, you can take string of "FF" and add the dollar sign as follow to it.

```
tmpstr := '$'+ 'FF';
```

Then, convert `tmpstr` string variable into an integer to get the actual hexidecimal. The result would be `255`.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to convert your `string` to an `int`:

```
var i = Int32.Parse("FF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Your example `1847504890` does not fit on an `int`, however. Use a longer type instead.

```
var i = Int64.Parse("1847504890", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple:

`int value = Convert.ToInt32("DEADBEEF", 16);`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by following

```
string tmpstr = "FF";
int num = Int32.Parse(tmpstr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

You can also see the link [Converting string to hex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
int hexval = Convert.ToInt32("FF", 16);
```