# How do you format variables in C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, formatting, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

In C, you can do something like

```
int x = 255;
printf("x is: %d and in HEX, x is: %x", x, x);
```

How can I do that in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) or [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)? Print the variable's hex equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 255;
Console.WriteLine("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {0:X}", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
Console.WriteLine("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {0:X}", x);
```

If you need only the string

```
string formatted = String.Format("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {0:X}", x);
```

This is called [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). `{n}` acts as placeholder for the parameters that follow, where `n` is the zero-based number of the parameter. You can specify an optional format after `:` in the placeholder.

You can convert an int to string by specifying a format

```
string hex = x.ToString("X");
```

Comment: You don't need to add `x` as a format parameter twice if you aren't changing it. You can reuse the same value in the format template. `Console.WriteLine("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {0:X}", x);` is the best approach.

Comment: @SliverNinja: Of cause you are right. I changed my example accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Format("{0:X}", number)`  to format as hex.

```
Console.Write(String.Format("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is : {0:X}", x));
```

Comment: How does this get printed to the screen? The OP wants the `printf` equivalent?

Comment: The question is how to format a string.  In C/C++, this was commonly done with a print directly.  In C#/VB that need not be the case.

Comment: Incorrect - [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) would be the equivalent of [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), whereas [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) would be the equivalent of [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx)

Comment: I didn't say it *couldn't* be done in C, I just said it's less commonly done.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int x = 500;
 Console.WriteLine("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {1:X}", x, x);
```

Would output

> x is: 500 and in HEX, x is: 1F4

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: [`Console.WriteLine` already takes a `StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c.aspx)

Comment: @SliverNinja true, but it can be useful for this particular case to demonstrate that it's using `string.Format` internally.  It will point him to the correct page(s) in the documentation more easily.

Comment: I personally would use String.Format but always useful to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The printf equivalent is [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
String.Format("{0:x}", 0xBEEF);
```

or just use the [`int.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y) method:

```
int MyInt = 0xBEEF;
MyInt.ToString("x");
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

`string.Format("x is: {0} and in HEX, x is: {1:X}", x, x);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ToString("X")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} hex equivalent =  {1}", 456, 456.ToString("X"));
```

[Covert to hex, and convert back](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB8_How-do-I-convert-from-decimal-to-hex-and-hex-to-decimal.html)