# 16-bit signed from ASCII hexadecimal sequence

Tags: c#, hex, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

I'm having struggle with converting to signed int using c#
lets say I have the fallowing string:

```
AAFE B4FE B8FE
```

here we have 3 samples. each sample (signed 16 bits) is written as an ASCII hexadecimal sequence of 4 digits (2x2 digits/byte).

any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify the endian-ness of the parsed values (instead of assuming that they are in little-endian byte order), then you need to place each `byte` in the appropriate place within the resulting `short`.

Note that exceptions will be thrown in `HexToByte` if the string values are not well formatted.

```
static byte HexToByte(string value, int offset)
{
   string hex = value.Substring(offset, 2);
   return byte.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

static short HexToSigned16(string value, bool isLittleEndian)
{
   byte first = HexToByte(value, 0);
   byte second = HexToByte(value, 2);

   if (isLittleEndian) 
       return (short)(first | (second << 8));
   else
       return (short)(second | (first << 8));
}

...

string[] values = "AAFE B4FE B8FE".Split();
foreach (string value in values)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} == {1}", value, HexToSigned16(value, true));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that's exactly what i needed.. my string is very well formatted

Answer (score 1):

You can parse strings of numbers of any standard base using overloads in the `Convert` class that accept a base.  In this case, you'd probably want [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wxkt09k.aspx) overload.

Then you could do something like this:

```
var groupings = "AAFE B4FE B8FE".Split();
var converted = groupings
    .Select(grouping => Convert.ToInt16(grouping, 16))
    .ToList();
```