# regular expression to check for special character "$"

Tags: java, regex

I have a string similar to this 9$1F , need to check whether it starts with digit followed by a "$" symbol and should end with a hex value.

```
[0-9][\\$][0-9A-Fa-f]
```

I tried something like this but it fails, can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using `.matches()` (which requires that the regex matches the entire input string), and your regex only matches the first hex digit.

Try

```
[0-9][$][0-9A-Fa-f]+
```

Instead of `[$]`, you can also use `\\$`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it gives me an number format exception for the input string "1$04".

Answer (score 2):

If it must absolutely start with a digit, try this:

```
^\\d\\$[0-9A-Fa-f]+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it gives me an number format exception for the input string "1$04. Yes, it should start with a digit, followed by "$" and should end with a hex value

Comment: What do you do with the match afterwards? Show the stacktrace of the exception are you getting?

Comment: Once it matches, i have to split the string with "$". I couldnt paste the stack trace as it says some indention problem. Will edit my post once Im done indenting

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1$04"

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a regex match you might as well just use that to split the string as well. The following example converts the digit and hex values into two separate integers.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9])\\$([0-9A-Fa-f]+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("9$FF");
int digit = 0;
int hex = 0;

if (matcher.find()) {
    digit = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    hex = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2), 16);
}
System.out.println(digit + " " + hex);
```

Results in `9 255` (`9` and `FF`)