# Convert hex number to int or byte then check result number in array of byte in c#?

Tags: c#

I have number "000001B6" (hexadecimal). I want to convert hex "000001B6" to integer or byte,  then search result number in array of byte to check if this number exists in array or not.

How can i do that in C#, such that:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[20];

number = 000001B6 // convert number to integer or byte then search result number in array
```

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c) could solve your problem

Comment: `0x1B6` (1B6_16 or 438_10) is larger than `byte.MaxValue` (FF_16 or 255_10). How would such a value be encoded in your `byte[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert the hexadecimal number to integer

```
string hexNumber = "000001B6";
int integerValue = int.Parse(hexNumber, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

You can only search for 255 as it is the maximum value for the `byte[]`, so you must be sure that you hexadecimal number should not be more than that.

But you example string ie. `00001B6` is equivalent to `438`. So you need to take care of the Range.

Otherwise you can simple use `.Any` function to check the existence inside the array.

```
bool isExists = temp.Any(x => x == integerValue);
```

Comment: ok thanks...but array of byte not contain definition of contains??

Comment: @user2898387 use `.Any`. See my update in my answer and let me if any problem found.

Comment: Use `int integerValue = 0x1B6;` if this is a literal. There's no point in changing from `Contains` to `Any`. Both are Linq extension methods. Neither exist on `byte[]`, but both will be in scope with a `using System.Linq;` directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] temp = new byte[20];
var i = int.Parse("000001B6", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); //438
if(i <= byte.MaxValue) //will never be true for 000001B6 since 438 > 255
    var hasValue = temp.Contains((byte)i);
```

Comment: Why not simply `temp.Contains(0x1B6)`? Why did you change to an `int[]`? Was that what the asker wanted?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the hex value is in a string format hence the parse. Also `0x1B6` is larger than what can fit into a `byte`.

Comment: Then you should explain that in your answer. The question seemed to talk about an array of bytes. Certainly `0x1B6` is the same as `int.Parse("000001B6", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)`, and since it has three hex digits, it will need a `short` or something wider. I just think your answer should elaborate on that. Otherwise it is not actually an answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Sure I'll try to make it more clear.