# Why does converting between decimal and hex throw a formatexception?

Tags: c#, .net, hex, decimal, .net-4.5

When I compile and run the below code, it throws the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: The specified format 'X' is invalid
>     at System.NumberFormatter.NumberToString (System.String format, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.NumberFormatter.NumberToString (System.String format, Decimal value, IFormatProvider fp) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Decimal.ToString (System.String format, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Decimal.ToString (System.String format) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Program.Main ()

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal result = 1454787509433225637;

                    //both these lines throw a formatexception
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("X"));
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:x}", result));
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223/1324019 this should compile fine (and output "14307188337151A5").

Comment: The other question uses the term decimal as in a base-10 number. It uses is formatting values of type `int` not `decimal`.

Comment: In the example they are using an int variable. I think you are confusing the decimal datatype with the common terminology used when you convert decimal(integer) to hex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for X format type you can use only Integral types only.

> Result: A hexadecimal string. 
>   **Supported by: Integral types only**.
>   Precision specifier: Number of digits in the result string. More
>   information: The HexaDecimal ("X") Format Specifier.

So you need to specify **int** instead of **decimal**. Because Hex format exists only for integral values.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
int result = 1454787509433225637;
```