# Convert very large integer number to hexadecimal and back again

Tags: c#, math, type-conversion, formatexception

I have a string type variable that represents 25-digit integer number in my c# code, for example 7590720001001011080190334.
I need to shrink the length of this number at least for 2-3 digit.
I thought that the easiest way is to convert this number into hexadecimal. I can't afford the bases with more capacity.

I checked out online services that decimal 7590720001001011080190334 (25 digit) is 64765C17B803752D9D97E (21 digit) in hex, that's good for me.
But in c# I faced a problem with the conversion between the bases.
The large numbers like mine I can store only in decimal type of variables but I get System.FormatException by doing this code:

```
decimal foo = 7590720001001011080190334m;
string bar = foo.ToString("X"); //throw System.FormatException
```

I saw in question [Why does converting between decimal and hex throw a formatexception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666474/why-does-converting-between-decimal-and-hex-throw-a-formatexception) that a hexadecimal string only supported by integral types in c#. That is too sad, cause some online services in javascript are possible to solve this problem.
Any thoughts how can I solve the conversation problem or the shrink problem?

Comment: Try `BigInteger` instead of `decimal`

Comment: Read the exception.  Looks like your format is trying to convert to a Date.

Comment: `var bigint = BigInteger.Parse("7590720001001011080190334");
Console.WriteLine(bigint.ToString("x"));`

Comment: What is the use case? Maybe [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1) can help?

Comment: @jdweng Hmm? It just says "Format specifier was invalid"

Comment: Sorry : The TIP says Date.  The actual message is "Format specifier was invalid."

Comment: Hex is not valid on a fractional number (float, decimal, double).  There is no representation of fractions in hex in Net Library.

Comment: _"I need to shrink the length of this number at least for 2-3 digit"_ & _" I can't afford the bases with more capacity."_ - if you let us know exactly what you are trying to do (why is 23 digits OK & not 25), then maybe we can help better.

Comment: Not a good dupe target in my opinion.