# Adding Currency code to textblock programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 app and need to add a currency hex code to a textblock text property programmatically. It works perfectly on xaml:

```
<TextBlock  Text="&#x20a6;" />
```

but when i use the statement below:

```
textblock.text = "&#x20a6;";
```

it just display the text as it is. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried this: `textblock.text = "\x20a6";`

Comment: @Simon tried it but not working, displays the string as it is

Comment: or this `textblock.text = "\u20a6";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Unicode value in the string.  [Using Unicode character escape sequences in strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
  textblock2.Text = "\u20a6";
```

Or you can use the hex number and convert to a char.

```
  textblock2.Text = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x20a6);
```

Also, you can simply use the character:

```
textblock2.Text = "₦";
```

Comment: Thanks, like the first and second example, works great

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            var formatter = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("HA-LATN-NG");
            formatter.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "₦";


            textblock.text  = long.Parse("20a6", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier 
            | NumberStyles.HexNumber,
            formatter).ToString("c");
```

But, if you need a decimal value, [see this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

Comment: this will retrieve the user's current region or currency format. I just need to work with a set of provided currency codes I have. the currency code 20a6 is for Nigeria naira