# How to convert hex to decimal in c#.net?

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

Convert Hex to Decimal

Example:

It would ask a Hex. Shown below.

Enter Hex: **8000 8000 1000 0100**

Then,

The Result: **32768 32768 4096 256**

Convert each hex to decimal.

HEX  = DECIMAL

8000 = 32768

8000 = 32768

1000 = 4096

0100 = 256

Comment: [Convert.ToString(Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or [Convert.ToInt32(string, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c

Comment: @Alexander - I already used that, it gives me an error. The program can only convert **8000** not the **8000 8000 1000 0100**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Enter HEX: ");
string hexValues = Console.ReadLine();
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine("HEX = DECIMAL");
foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
    // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer. 
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", hex, Convert.ToDecimal(value)));
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

P.S. : The original code does not belong to me. For original codes please refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

[image]

Comment: I inputted **8000 8000 0100** the result was this **{0} = {1} 0100=256** the program only display the 3rd group of number.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed typos and quotations. Now it should wok.

Comment: What's the equivalent of Console.ReadKey() in Winforms?

Comment: There is no equivalent. This is a Console Application spesific command which pauses and waits the user to press any key. It is just used to keep the application windows open until you press a key. In WinForms you do not need such an action. Form is displayed until you hide or slose it.

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll** in this line **TxttText.Text = string.Format("{0} = {1}" + "=" + hex + "=" + Convert.ToDecimal(value));**

Comment: Why did you added additional "=" strings? They distort the string.Format() method paremeters. It is a method that gets  format string and parameters only. It sewlf constructs the string. You should not do it. If you want to format string then do not use Format() method. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already erase the string.Format() but still having a problem of the output. It only display the answer of 3rd group of number.

Comment: I don't know what but you are doing something wrong. Please check the image I have added to the answer.

Comment: I already got it. I just put '+' before the '=' sign. Thanks for helping me. 'Til next time.

Answer (score 2):

use string.split(' ') to get your individual hex-numbers as a string-array. Then you can call

```
int dec = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

to convert each hex into its decimal representation.