# Converting float to hex format

Tags: c#, hex

Given the following variable:

```
float myFloat = 0xC0451EB8;
```

How do I get C0451EB8 from myFloat?

Edit: Not sure why I am being down voted here with no comment. I am not asking a simple hex representation of a float or uint32. I can do this. Given the variable definition above and a [possible common] answer of:

```
string FloatAsHex(float myFloat) {
  return BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(myFloat));
}

FloatToHex(0xC0451EB8); //will output 1F-45-40-4F, not what I expect
FloatToHex(BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(0xC0451EB8))) //works
```

Although the second one obviously works, I only have access to the float variable.

Comment: You mean asa string ?

Comment: Yes, as a string or byte[] - I just would like to reverse the conversion.

Comment: You can try using `.ToString("x")` but this probably would require casting to double or int

Comment: My apologies for the incorrect duplicate target. Your question is actually a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c. Though, given a `float` with that value, you cannot literally do what you want, because as soon as you store `0xC0451EB8` into a `float` variable, you lose precision. You can `((uint)myFloat).ToString("X")`, which will get you `"C0451F00"`, which is as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you, I had a feeling i was using an unsafe value and losing precision but I was tearing my hair out over the conversion. I thought I had read every possible float to hex conversion topic on SO but I guess I overlooked this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish what you're asking. Your code is storing the integer value `0xC0451EB8`, or in decimal `3225755320`, in a variable of type `float`. The integer value has 32 bits of precision, but a `float` cannot represent 32 bits of numeric precision, because some of the 32 bits of the `float` value are committed to the exponent.

Thus, the integer value `3225755320` gets truncated to `3225755392`.

You can cast the `float` back to `uint`, and then use the standard mechanism for formatting as a hexadecimal string value. E.g. `((uint)myFloat).ToString("X")`. But when you do that, you'll be starting with the truncated value, and the output will be `"C0451F00"` (or `"0xC0451F00"` if you include the standard hex specifier prefix in your format string).

Once you truncate the original value, there is no way to recover it. You cannot reverse the process.

Comment: Thanks Peter, unsurprisingly I didn't even try the simple cast to an unsigned integer then get a formatted string. This works for now. Thank you also for your detailed explanation, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says to use `BitConverter.ToString Method (Byte[])`
[on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will return a string representation of the number in hex base.
Example (for array of bytes representing a number):

```
00-01-02-04-08-10-20-40-80-FF
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. This will output 1F-40-45-1F, where I would expect it to output B8-1E-45-C0