# Converting a hex string to a dec string

Tags: c#, numbers, numeric

I'm currently tasked with building a programm that can convert different numeric strings into other number systems I've been mostly using methods similar to this

```
    string ConvToDec(string input)
    {
        return String.Join(".", (input.Split('.').Select(x => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(x, 2)))).ToArray());
    }
```

To convert, which I can't seem to get working when I want to convert from Hex to Dec. I've tried a few solutions I've found on here like the ones found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c) thread, but nothing seemed to work for me.

Comment: Can you show what's on input? Also `ConvToDec` sounds misleading, if your input always a hex string, then name it something like `ConvHexToDec` or something.

Comment: @SeM input will be the contents of a textbox, executed it looks like this
    
    `TextBox2.Text = ConvToDec(TextBox1.Text);`

Comment: It doesn't really matter from where your input will come. Can you show what you have on your input (what have you tested)?

Comment: That's another method I am using and I actually got to work properly, as an example of how it is 'supposed' to look like. Anyhow, I test it like [this](https://i.imgur.com/CbWvicH.png)

Comment: Can you just add a `string input` value into your question please?

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*, please? Input and the desired output?

Comment: You need to be clearer about your input and output. A 'hex-string' could have any length. A 'decimal string', too. But the conversion is not clear at all. If it is supposed to be a number the length/size is important and limited. If you want to use it in a hex-editor it is not about numbers but about bytes..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert numbers between hexadecimal and decimal in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148/how-to-convert-numbers-between-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt32(x, 2)` converts a binary number string to an int (that's what the `2` says).

Use `Convert.ToInt32(x, 16)` in your expression above to convert a hex string to an int.

Input `c0.80` will then give `192.128` as output.